# Using ajax post to transfer data from JS to a function in Controller in asp.net mvc. But the view is not changed

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This is code in JS file for Transferring data.

```
          var requestData = {
                lati: latitude,
                longi: longitude
            };

            $.ajax({
                url: '/User/populate_place',
                type: 'POST',
                data: requestData,
                dataType: 'json'
            });
```

This  is my Function in controller.

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult populate_place(string lati, string longi)
    {
        list_placesModels list_place = new list_placesModels();
        list_place.Latitude = lati;
        list_place.Longitude = longi;

        return RedirectToAction("About", "Home");
    }
```

While Debugging the program Function is called but view is not changed. It still shows the old view.

Comment: You don't have to stringify the data in the POST.
After on .NET side, work with the function argument not as a string but as an object.

Comment: I used the above code without stringify the data. Still view is not changing.

Comment: Did you try receiving the URL string as JSON response and redrecting to the returned URL from javascript like document.location="http://www.foo.com/ ? NOTE: You can make use of Url.Action(...) with one of the suitable overloads so that you can generate URLs' in compliance with your application specific routing config.

Comment: No Didn't tried that and i am new to JSON and JS so can you please elaborate what you exactly you want me to try ??

Comment: Please find the detailed steps in my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your hitting the controller via ajax the response wont affect the page the user sees, the response is not being handled, you would need to add a success: handler to the ajax code. But, if this call will always result in the user being forwarded to another page you don't need to do it ajax, you can just use a normal mvc ActionLink like below.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link text", "populate_place", "user", new {lati = latiValue, longi = longiValue}, null)
```

*UPDATE*

I think you'll have to do something like below, I'm not sure why success isn't getting hit but it works if you use complete, that would need looking into. The mvc controller will have to return the url and the ajax response handler will need to redirect to that url.

*corrected based on **Siva Gopal's** answer*

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public string populate_place(string lati, string longi)
    {
        return Url.Action("About", "Home").ToString();
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/populate_place',
        type: 'POST',
        data: requestData,
        dataType: 'json',
        complete: function (data) {
            document.location = data.responseText;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey, i want to use ajax for transferring the data. Data is transferred but view is not changed ?? and also the above method that you mentioned doesn't seems to work. As using the above shows that latiValue and longiValue are doesn't exist in the current context. and Conditional Compilation is turned Off.

Comment: the latiValue and longiValue represent the values you want to pass into the controller, im not sure how you would change these via javascript, so maybe the answer is to add a success handler to the ajax call that forwards to a url. I'm having a play now.

Comment: I am not changing the latiValue and longiValue. Basically i am using Google api to get the latitude and longitude when user search about some place. I want those latitude and longitude to be passed from JS to my function in controller.

Comment: I've updated my answer and it works locally for me, the implementation is based on @Siva Gopal answer if I'm honest as i didn't know how to do it, but its doing what i suggested earlier.

Comment: Kudos!!! Thanks a ton. The above code solved my problem. Now i am able to redirect to new url and also pass my data. Thanks a lot lot :)

Comment: No problem glad i could help, we got there in the end lol. One point though, you need to get the ajax call working with success rather than complete and add some kind of error handling if its going to be used in a production environment.

Comment: Thanks a lot i will add error handling and what is difference between ajax call working with success and complete. Actually i am new to ajax so i don't know much about this.

Comment: Success will only be hit if the http request returns a successfull http code, 200 for example. Complete will fire regardless of the outcome of the http request, and you dont want your app redirecting if the ajax request fails. see jquery documentation for more info http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Answer (score 3):

One of the simple way, you can hand-off URL to client to handle on their own can by done by having a action method like:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult MyRedirectAction()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";
            return Json(Url.Action("About", "Home")); //You can find how i am returing the url 
                                                      // for 'About' action of 'HomeController' so that 
                                                      // it will return the corresponding view.
        }
public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }
```

and now in your view script(may be Jquery) you can redirect as shown below:

```
<input type="button" id="btnRedirectToAbout" value="Redirect To About" />

<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1-vsdoc.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#btnRedirectToAbout").click(function () {
        $.post('@Url.Action("MyRedirectAction","Home")', function (data) {
            document.location = data;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I hope this can help you to fix your problem.

Comment: Hey i used the modified code by tom and it worked. Thanks a lot for help :)